# How to remove/erase rows from a selection of a tree view

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I want to remove selected rows from a treeview or the underlying model.

The following code snipped works, but I have no idea which function of which class I have to call to remove the selected elements.

```
std::vector<Gtk::TreeModel::Path> pathlist;
pathlist = get_selection()->get_selected_rows();


for ( std::vector<Gtk::TreeModel::Path>::iterator it = pathlist.begin(); it!=pathlist.end(); it++)
{
    Gtk::TreeModel::iterator iter = get_model()->get_iter( *it );
    Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *iter;

    int val;
    std::string str;

    row.get_value( 0, val );
    row.get_value( 1, str );

    std::cout << "val " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "String:" << str << std::endl;
}
```

The above code works fine.

Now I want to delete the elements which are selected!
Attention: MULTIPLE selection is activated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the main problem is MULTIPLE selection - if you get only one item then it's simple:

```
get_model()->erase(iter);
```

The problem is after that; the rest of iterators become invalid.

Do you have any unique ID for each row? If YES, then you can use that:

1. Store all IDs in container
2. go throu all items and delete the stored

something like that:

```
std::vector<Gtk::TreeModel::Path> pathlist;
pathlist = get_selection()->get_selected_rows();

std::set<int> IDs;

for ( std::vector<Gtk::TreeModel::Path>::iterator it = pathlist.begin(); it!=pathlist.end(); it++)
{
    Gtk::TreeModel::iterator iter = get_model()->get_iter( *it );
    iter->get_value(ID, id);

    IDs.insert(id);
}

auto iter = get_model()->erase( get_model()->get_iter( *pathlist.begin() );
while (iter) 
{
    int id;
    iter->get_value(ID, id);
    if (IDs.find(id) != IDs.end()) {
        iter = get_model()->erase( iter );
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

Or something like that. Sorry, I don't remember whole API.

I assume that erasing row from model changes also PATH.